# Javascript/jQuery If Condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently having an issue getting my jQuery if statement to work. I have been looking at online tutorials on if statements in Javascript as well as the documentation on jQuery to try and get this to work however still can not manage to. I have included a snippet of my JS below.

```
($('#modem-include').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("btn-info")) {
        $(this).addClass("btn-success");
        $(this).removeClass("btn-info");
        $(this).text("SELECTED");
    } else {
        $(this).text("SELECTED");
    }
    if ($('#modem-nothanks').hasClass("btn-success")) {
        $(this).addClass("btn-info");
        $(this).removeClass("btn-success");
        $(this).text("SELECT");
    } else {
        $(this).text("SELECT");
    }
}));
($('#modem-nothanks').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("btn-info")) {
        $(this).addClass("btn-success");
        $(this).removeClass("btn-info");
        $(this).text("SELECTED");
    } else {
        $(this).text("SELECTED");
    }
    if ($('#modem-include').hasClass("btn-success")) {
        $(this).addClass("btn-info");
        $(this).removeClass("btn-success");
        $(this).text("SELECT");
    } else {
        $(this).text("SELECT");
    }
}));
```

No matter what I try this does not seem to work.

Wondering if I am missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "does not seem to work"? what is not working?

Comment: `this` is referencing a DOM element, which is not the same as a jQuery object. Observe the errors in your developer console.

Comment: Substitute `this` by `$(this)`. You need to convert the DOM object into a jQuery entity.

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ The class and text both aren't changing, they are staying the same as they were previously (as if it's not acknowledging the click).

Comment: Your code always ends up in `this.text("SELECT");`. Remove both `else` parts. Please explain what you expect the code to do, because it makes no sense as it is now.

Comment: @JavierRey I have only grabbed one of the click functions in the above code snippet. The code runs on click and changes the 2 options, as to if the modem is included or not. Changing the button style and text. I am using the if statements to ensure that the classes are removed and added properly between clicks. - Updated the code to show what I mean.

Comment: All `this`, which should be `$(this)`, in the code refer to `$('#modem-include')`, right?

Comment: @JavierRey the first lot do, the ones in the second if statement refer to `$('#modem-nothanks')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it right (which I'm not sure), try something like:

```
$('#modem-include').click(function () {
  var $this = $(this), $that = $('#modem-nothanks');
  if ($this.hasClass("btn-info")) {
      $this.removeClass("btn-info");
      $this.addClass("btn-success");
      $this.text("SELECTED");
  } else {
      $this.text("SELECT");
  }
  if ($that.hasClass("btn-success")) {
      $that.removeClass("btn-success");
      $that.addClass("btn-info");
      $that.text("SELECT");
  } else {
      $that.text("SELECTED");
  }
});
$('#modem-nothanks').click(function () {
  var $this = $(this), $that = $('#modem-include');
  if ($this.hasClass("btn-info")) {
      $this.removeClass("btn-info");
      $this.addClass("btn-success");
      $this.text("SELECTED");
  } else {
      $this.text("SELECT");
  }
  if ($that.hasClass("btn-success")) {
      $that.removeClass("btn-success");
      $that.addClass("btn-info");
      $that.text("SELECT");
  } else {
      $that.text("SELECTED");
  }
});
```

Comment: Good! I edited the final answer to make the right SELECT/SELECTED options.

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly, just had to make one small change so that the buttons always changed text to the required value depending on what's clicked (if the `btn-success` class was set I needed `"SELECTED"` otherwise I needed `"SELECT"` but that was very easy to change. Your code was very easy to understand as well.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the ids and classes so they are easier to follow while they flip-flop. To fix your code just be mindful of `this`, because it's a reference to the owner of the function. So the first half of each function the selectors were correct, but the second half of each function, the selectors were not `this`. The way you can tell is if the selector started of as either the origin of an event (`event.target`) or it is delegating an event (`.on()`).

**Note:** I placed the `SELECT` and `SELECTED` text in a separate `output`.

#### SNIPPET

```js
$('#yes').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("btn-info")) {
    $(this).addClass("btn-success").removeClass("btn-info")
    $('#yesOut').text("SELECTED");

    if ($('#no').hasClass("btn-success")) {
      $('#no').addClass("btn-info").removeClass("btn-success");
      $('#noOut').text("SELECT");
    }
  }
});
$('#no').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("btn-info")) {
    $(this).addClass("btn-success").removeClass("btn-info");
    $('#noOut').text("SELECTED");

    if ($('#yes').hasClass("btn-success")) {
      $('#yes').addClass("btn-info").removeClass("btn-success");
      $('#yesOut').text("SELECT");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<fieldset>
  <legend>Yes/No</legend>
  <button id='no' class='btn btn-info'>NO</button><br/>
  <label for='noOut'>Status on NO</label>
  <output id='noOut'></output>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <button id='yes' class='btn btn-info'>YES</button><br/>
  <label for='yesOut'>Status on YES</label>
  <output id='yesOut'></output>
</fieldset>
```